# CSS media queries not being triggered at defined width

Tags: html, css

CSS media queries not being triggered at defined width instead triggered from the next higher resolution media query.

For eg the width from 959px to 974px is supposed to take 730px but end up taking 950px .....the same issue with another specific width 1145 to 1183 ends up taking the larger max-width mentioned outside media query instead of 950px, two specific places where it fails.

```
.cwidth{
    max-width:1147px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 754px) and (max-width:975px){
    .cwidth{
        max-width:730px !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 976px) and (max-width:1183px){
    .cwidth{
        max-width:950px !important;
    }
}
```

(i have written the queries at the bottom of the style sheet, made sure i have no inline style for the element, also have tried without the !important tag.)

[The result required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhUOX.jpg)

[but the result i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H9hH.jpg)

Comment: @AdrianKokot You can chain `and`s according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#combining_multiple_types_or_features)

Comment: @AdrianKokot Yes you can https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: These queries seem fine to me: [Test jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scq1y43n/). Can you add a snippet to your question that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @DBS i have added the snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  @media (min-width: 754px) and (max-width: 975px) {
    .cwidth{
      max-width:730px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 976px) and (max-width: 1183px) {
    .cwidth{
      max-width:950px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried that the issue still persists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try using max-width first and then min-width**

And no need to use **!important** property

```
.cwidth{
    max-width:1147px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1183px) and (min-width: 976px) {
    .cwidth {
        max-width: 950px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 975px) and (min-width: 754px) {
    .cwidth {
        max-width: 730px;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, have tried both no luck!!

Comment: this code will work for sure! Please share your code for reference. Refer this code and check - https://codepen.io/rockytechtips/pen/qBXVYrK

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working perfectly fine when i just increased to a specific interval such as this that I am providing below in code instead of the one i gave earlier:

```
.cwidth{
    max-width:1147px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
@media (min-width: 754px) and (max-width:993px){
    .cwidth{
        max-width:730px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width:1199.5px){
    .cwidth{
        max-width:950px;
    }
}
```

(I just kept on increasing the interval till it aligned perfectly.)